# How to use the data target in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

```
<button id="btn-id" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</a>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other contents for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sports</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Activities</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I can get this error:

The 'data-target' attribute value should be the id of the  tag for toggling elements like navigation links, forms, and other contents

I need a solution for this error.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably missing to include the bootstrap js assets because the collapse feature requires that also and the css is not enough.

I'm taking for granted we are talking about Bootstrap 4.0 since that's the tag you used in your question.

This is the official page documenting the collapse feature:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

This is the official page documenting the assets:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

I show it here:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button
  id="btn-id"
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
    Collapse
</button>

<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</a>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other contents for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sports</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This code cannot work ....same error occurred sir

Comment: I'm afraid you are having problems beyond the code itself because here it's working correctly in the demo when I run the code snippet. Did you try? what's the error you are encountering? and which browser are you using? do you have javascript enabled?

Comment: my code runs successfully in the online compiler but did not pass all the test cases. It shows that error

Comment: it depends on what kind of tester you are using.. maybe it expects that attribute to match the exact id and not the selector (including the `#`). By the way I showed the way bootstrap wants that attribute to be and how it's documented in their page. It was useful if you were more clear in your question saying who was giving you the error and now it's clear we are not talking about the js runtime. The snippet itself is perfectly valid and any other issue you might have could depend on the whole picture not showed here in the question. So _"this code cannot work"_ is not true because it works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @Diego , it seems that bootstrap.js is not included. Take care about the thing that jQuery should be included too, and before bootstrap.js.

[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#breaking)  still requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but you’re advised to use version 3.x since v3.x’s supported browsers are the ones Bootstrap supports plus v3.x has some security fixes.

You don’t need jQuery in [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery) (the last one today(Nov 2022), but take care because you used bootstrap-4 tag in your post, i don't really know which one you use), but it’s still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects jQuery in the window object, it’ll add all of our components in jQuery’s plugin system.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to make MyBrand as navbar toggler icon

[image]

full code used above

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <button id="btn-id" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
    MyBrand
  </button>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other contents for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sports</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Activities</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

        




</body>
</html>
```